# strcmp isn't comparing strings properly

Tags: c

So I have this (not the full code)

`char list[1000][10];`

`strcpy(list[0],"ab");`

`printf("%d\n",strcmp(list[0],"ab"));`

and the strcmp is returning 0. Can somebody explain why it's doing so?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because the two compared strings are equal, so `strcmp` returns `0`.

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp, http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strcmp.html, or just `man strcmp` if your system has the `man` command.

Comment: See [`strcmp()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) (and I advise drilling up a few levels and spending some time on that entire site for awhile).

Comment: @WhozCraig Rather [this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strcmp.html). We are in C, not in C++.

Comment: I see you're also on the Mathematics board.  Keep in mind, if you're used to writing stuff in Matlab, that its `strcmp()` behaves differently (it returns 1 for equality whereas C's `strcmp()` returns 0).

Comment: Here is an interesting idea - read the manual page? Might get a better understanding and answer quicker

Comment: @H2CO3 Um. did you check that link before correcting me? Look again. its the C-subsection of the side, not `std::strcmp()`. Sok the more sights he has to see the better IMHO.

Comment: @WhozCraig Correct... it's just that the `cppreference.com` URL misled me. :(

Comment: @H2CO3 No worries man. Totally understandable. Just didn't want you thinking I'd lost my marbles more than I already have =P.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`strcmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) method will return 0 if `list[0]` contains "ab" in this case.

It returns:

> Returns an integral value indicating the relationship between the strings:
>
> A zero value indicates that both strings are equal.
>
> A value greater than zero indicates that the first character that does not match has a greater value in str1 than in str2; And a value less than zero indicates the opposite.

Comment: oh. I thought functions usually return 1 when they're true. This was a stupid mistake of mine. Sorry.

Comment: @HasanSaad: It depends on the function. `strcmp` doesn't return a true or false value. Never attempt to use any function until you've read the documentation for that function.

Comment: @HasanSaad "I thought" - don't do that. **Don't make assumptions. *Never.*** Read the documentation.

Comment: @HasanSaad: `strcmp` doesn’t return “true” or “false”; it returns a comparison result (negative if a < b, zero if a = b, positive if a > b).

Comment: @HasanSaad That's true in some cases, but every function can be different.  `strcmp` is used to compare, so it returns postive/zero/negative.

Answer (score 0):

`strmp` returns 0 when the strings match. Unless I am missing something, it's behaving as expected.

see: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ansi_c/c_strcmp.htm

Answer (score 0):

`strcmp()` does an *ordinal comparison* of the strings, not an *equality* test. The return value of 0 means the strings are equal!

If you want to test for equality use this pattern:

```
if (strcmp(s, "ab") == 0) {
    // strings are equal
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `strcpy()` is a function that copies the "right" string to the "left" string.
So, after `strcpy(list[0],"ab");`, the content of `list[0]` is "ab".
Then, they are equal strings, and strcmp returns 0, which means "equal".

Answer (score 0):

Your String is matched that is why it is returning 0
do like this...

```
    char list[1000][10];

    strcpy(list[0],"ab");
    if(strcmp(list[0],"ab")==0)
         printf("Matched\n",);
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Daniel, the returnd value is 0.

Taken from [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncmp/?kw=strncmp)

> Returns an integral value indicating the relationship between the
>   strings:  A zero value indicates that the characters compared in both
>   strings form the same string.  A value greater than zero indicates
>   that the first character that does not match has a greater value in
>   str1 than in str2; And a value less than zero indicates the opposite.

You should also work with `strncmp` rather than with `strcmp`.

Comment: `strncmp` is not always better than `strcmp`. As long as you know both arguments are valid strings, and you want to compare the entire strings and not just an initial substring, `strcmp` is fine.

Comment: No cplusplus.com, please. Firstly, the question is tagged C. Second, cplusplus.com is a horrible site with utter inaccuracies. [this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strcmp.html) is better.

Comment: It may be, that cplusplus.com is a horrible site and mostly about C++. But in this case the answer seems to be fine and the reference is also about C. And good point by Keith, he is right.